# how can i rewrite url with this char ~

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to Rewrite simple url like that

```
test.com/test.php?code=12345
```

to

```
test.com/12345
```

when the user enter this link go to the shortened link
and when the user enter the character `~` in the last of url show the link info
like that

```
test.com/12345~
```

can any one help me by writing the code for this using `.htaccess` ?

I want to make it like bit.ly when you write the shortened it's go to the url when you add + to the end of the url in bit.ly it gives you the info of the shortened link

Comment: I don't know, but I think that you need to specify the type of web server you are using

Comment: Like some link shorteners? Bit.do : `bit.do/easy-`